# Default radio button selected but dropdown not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a website with a credit card payment form on it that I have used on other very similar websites. I am having a problem in that when the page loads, the credit card payment option is automatically selected and normally the dropdown list of credit cards shows. However, on this site the list is not showing until a second click occurs on the radio button which is showing as already selected. If anyone has any information as to what might be causing this I would be very grateful indeed! The problem can be seen at `www.seed-city.com` ([NSFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work)) if you add anything to your cart and view the cart page. Thank you for your time.

You can see the problem here:

http://www.seed-city.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.cart&add_id[]=270&qadd_270=10

The code I have is:

```
<div class="yagendoo_vm_checkout_credit_input">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td nowrap width="10%" align="left"><?php echo $VM_LANG->_('VM_CREDIT_CARD_TYPE'); ?>:</td>
                <td>          
                    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
                        writeDynaList( 'class="inputbox" name="creditcard_code" size="1"',
                        orders, originalPos, originalPos, originalOrder );
                        //-->
                    </script>
                    <?php 
                        $db_cc->reset();
                        $payment_class = $db_cc->f("payment_class");
                        $require_cvv_code = "YES";
                        if(file_exists(CLASSPATH."payment/$payment_class.php") && file_exists(CLASSPATH."payment/$payment_class.cfg.php")):
                            require_once(CLASSPATH."payment/$payment_class.php");
                            require_once(CLASSPATH."payment/$payment_class.cfg.php");
                            $_PAYMENT = new $payment_class();
                            if( defined( $_PAYMENT->payment_code.'_CHECK_CARD_CODE')):?>
                                <?php $require_cvv_code = strtoupper( constant($_PAYMENT->payment_code.'_CHECK_CARD_CODE'));?>
                            <?php endif;
                    endif;?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td nowrap width="10%" align="left">
                    <label for="order_payment_name">
                        <?php echo $VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_CHECKOUT_CONF_PAYINFO_NAMECARD') ?>:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="inputbox" id="order_payment_name" name="order_payment_name" value="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_name'])) echo $_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_name'] ?>" autocomplete="off" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td nowrap width="10%" align="left">
                    <label for="order_payment_number"><?php echo $VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_CHECKOUT_CONF_PAYINFO_CCNUM') ?>:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="inputbox" id="order_payment_number" name="order_payment_number" value="<?php if(!empty($_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number'])) echo $_SESSION['ccdata']['order_payment_number'] ?>" autocomplete="off" />
```

More code:

```
        foreach( $cards as $code => $name ) {

            $script .= "orders[".$i++."] = new Array( '".addslashes($db_cc->f("payment_method_name"))."','$code','$name' );\n";

        }



        }

        $script .= "function changeCreditCardList() { \n";

        $script .= "var selected_payment = null;

  for (var i=0; i<document.adminForm.payment_method_id.length; i++)

     if (document.adminForm.payment_method_id[i].checked)

        selected_payment = document.adminForm.payment_method_id[i].id;\n";

        $script .="changeDynaList('creditcard_code',orders,selected_payment, originalPos, originalOrder);\n";

        $script .="}\n";

        $script .="//-->\n";

        $script .="</script>\n";

        $script .= '<noscript>'.ps_html::selectList('creditcard_code', key($cards), $cards ).'</noscript>';

        return $script;

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share with us? Have you checked a debugger to see if there are any errors during page load?

Comment: Please give a heads up about the site's content and provide a SFW code sample.

Comment: For what it's worth, the issue is legit. I can recreate it. But ditto the other comments: it was a lot of effort to recreate your issue when you could've given us a sample easy enough.

Comment: Hello, this isn't spam. I could paste in the code I have but there seems to be quite a lot of different areas referencing the same thing, I will edit the post now with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a select with no items:

```
<select class="inputbox" name="creditcard_code" size="1"> </select>
```

The items are loaded via the script above it

```
/*<![CDATA[*/var originalOrder = '1';
var originalPos = 'payment_method_id_3';
var orders = new Array();   // array in the format [key,value,text]
orders[0] = new Array( 'payment_method_id_3','VISA','Visa' );
orders[1] = new Array( 'payment_method_id_3','MC','MasterCard' );
orders[2] = new Array( 'payment_method_id_3','jcb','JCB' );
orders[3] = new Array( 'payment_method_id_3','australian_bc','Australian Bankcard' );
orders[4] = new Array( 'payment_method_id_3','SWITCH','Maestro' );
function changeCreditCardList() { 
var selected_payment = null;
      for (var i=0; i<document.adminForm.payment_method_id.length; i++)
         if (document.adminForm.payment_method_id[i].checked)
            selected_payment = document.adminForm.payment_method_id[i].id;
op_changeDynaList('creditcard_code',orders,selected_payment, originalPos, originalOrder);
}/*]]>*/
```

I assume the `op_changeDynaList` function is supposed to load the `select` with the array. And it seems that `changeCreditCardList` is probably the `onchange` handler.

Again, this is stuff that should be in the question. But, I don't see where the list is actually loaded the first time. You probably need to call one of the functions (like `changeCreditCardList`) manually after the page loads, rather than waiting for the first event to be fired.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. It is greatly appreciated! So, what is happening is that it is loading but as there is the potential for 2 or more credit card payment options it is not loading the list of credit cards and requires another click. Could you give me a hint as to how I can call the function manually after the page loads? I am including some more code that I think is relevant and is where the script comes from.

Comment: I noticed that after the cart loads (with an appropriate order amount), it looks like there may be some javascript loading the payment information. I mean, it appears to pop into the screen after the page itself has completed loading. If calling `changeCreditCardList();` manually will correct the issue, it needs to be called sometime after the credit card form loads. So whatever script is loading that CC form, somewhere, as a last action, call the function that loads the credit card list (which may be `changeCreditCardList()`).